# Api call constraint reference for multiple params not honored

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

Only the first [*constraint reference,*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-constraint-reference) `{userid:guid:required}` is validated when calling the API.

The second parameter, `{key:maxlength(5):required}` is **not** validated. What is wrong here, is this a framework bug?

```
[HttpDelete("{userid:guid:required}/{key:maxlength(5):required}")]
[Route("deletefavorite")]
public ActionResult<Favorites> DeleteFavorites([FromQuery]Guid userId, [FromQuery]string key)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

    return NotFound($"Error 404: Could not delete {key}");
}
```

I'm building a *.Net Core 2.2 API* for an Single Page Application(SPA)

Comment: What is the exact URL you request to hit this action?

Comment: It is " https://mydns/api/deletefavorite/?userid=d06b76ee-... .&key=12345", the guid part is validated but not the key. I can validate it manually but this should work and that bugs me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    [Route("deletefavorite")]
    public ActionResult<Favorites> DeleteFavorites([FromQuery][Required]Guid userId, [FromQuery][Required][MaxLength(5)]string key)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

        return NotFound($"Error 404: Could not delete {key}");
    }
```

Output

```
{
    "key": ["The field key must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '5'."]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But still not sure why the other `DataAnnotations` didn't work.